# Нужно написать редирект с корня сайта в дочернюю папку

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно сделать редирект с корня сайта (site.ru) в дочернюю папку с другим сайтом (site.ru/site2) таким образом, чтобы он либо работал на поддомене вида site2.site.ru, либо как-нибудь настроить редирект так, чтобы по адресу site.ru открывался site2 (если это возможно).

Написал так: 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/site2/$1 [L,R=301]
Но это просто редирект на дочернюю папку, в результате чего увидим в адресной строке site.ru/site2/
А нужно либо site2.site.ru, либо site.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... чтобы по адресу site.ru открывался site2 (если это возможно).

Возможно.

Поменяйте сайту `site.ru` *DocumentRoot* на путь к `site.ru/site2`